# How to use "Greeked Text" —or fake content— to reduce anxiety in cases of long loading times

Tags: response-time, loading, facebook, lazy-loading

In cases where loading times are too long (more than a minute) does showing fake content or content placeholders while the application is loading data help reduce anxiety?

I've only seen this in Facebook's mobile App:

[image: Facebook fake loading]

Comment: Since I asked this question this has become a fairly common design pattern that is now used both in mobile and desktop. Luke Wroblewski calls them Skeleton Screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This link/information should help you: **Facebook content placeholder deconstruction** - http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html

To summarize the link information:

> **Why would I ever use this**? We can’t always remove having to wait for
>   information but we can make the wait feel shorter. By giving some
>   indication of what is going on and giving visual stimulus the user
>   feels immediately more comfortable and less likely to leave. This is
>   exactly like putting a progress bar on a long action. Apart from the
>   fact it’s some fancy polish, it’s great usability. I think this
>   feature is better than your average loading symbol because it actually
>   feels like the content is almost there.

Implementation aspect:

1) Its a **set of div's**.

2) There is a **centered wrapper element/div** -
[image]

3) Then there is the **Animated background element**: It’s a box that is has a animated background and that background happens to be a CSS gradient.
[image]

4) On top of this element are, **Plenty of Tiny Masking Blocks** - It’s just lots of little white divs that sit on top so you can’t see the animation. 
[image]

Source: http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot, Amit!!

Comment: Np, Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

We usually use a div. Make certain that the text is not confused with real text - but at the same time don't use lorem ipsum. (That will annoy or confuse your visitors.)

Try something along the line as:

> This page is taking a longer time to load than expected. (Something
>   interesting and relevant goes here.)